# The use of \pause in beamer is causing the unnecessary addition of headers

Tags: beamer, pause

I'm trying to use Beamer to create a presentation however I've got a problem when trying to use `\pause` to create an overlay.

The following is the code I'm working with...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\title[Gene Gain and Loss in the White Rust Pathogen]{Gene Gain and Loss during Evolution of Obligate Parasitism in the White Rust Pathogen of \textit{Arabidopsis thaliana}}
\subtitle[]{\scriptsize Eric Kemen, Anastasia Gardiner, Torsten Schultz-Larsen, Ariane C. Kemen, 
\\Alexi L. Balmuth,
Alexandre Robert-Seilaniantz, Kate Bailey, Eric Holub,\\ David J. Studholme, Dan MacLean,
Jonathan D. G. Jones}
\author[Ben]{Ben}
\date[30/01/2013]{30$^\text{th}$ January 2013}
\institute{Imperial College London}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Study Background}

\section{Study Background}
\begin{itemize}
\item It has been proposed, but not shown, that obligate biotrophy results from:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Reduced selection for maintenance of biosynthetic pathways \pause
\item Gain of mechanisms to evade host recognition or suppress host defence \pause 
\end{enumerate}
\item Previous research on powdery mildew fungus \textit{Blumeria graminis} or downy mildew oomycete \textit{Hyaloperonospora arabidopsidis} reveals a close correlation between the parasitism and massive gene losses in primary and secondary metabolism
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Study Methodology}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Study Methodology}

\end{frame}

\section{Study Results}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Study Results}

\end{frame}

\section{Author's Discussion}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Author's Discussion}

\end{frame}

\section{Conclusions}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Conclusions}
\framesubtitle{Implications, and Future Directions}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

After using the `\pause` commands in the "Study Background" slide I get the same section appended to the header of each slide for each pause.. more visually I mean this

[image: Unnecessary addition of section headers]

Any idea how to rectify this so there's just one section header as I suspect should be the case?

Comment: The `\section` command should go *outside* the `frame` environment.  As it is, it is being called for each slide in the frame so TeX thinks that your document has 3 sections called "Study Background".

Comment: Oh dear, I'm constantly making silly mistakes, thanks a lot!

Comment: Simple mistake that is easy to make but hard to spot.  That's good that that worked (I posted as a comment as I wasn't completely sure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By putting the `\section` command *inside* the frame environment you are ensuring that it is executed for each overlay of that frame.  The use of the `\pause` command then ensures that this is done more than once.  So LaTeX thinks that you have three sections called "Study Background" because that particular `\section` command is executed three times.

It is possible to adapt a LaTeX command to be more "overlay aware" in the sense that it only has its desired effect once per frame - the usual use of this is with counters that need to be hold their value across each overlay.  But in this case the simpler solution is the better one: simply move the `\section` command out of the `frame` environment (as you have with the later `\section` commands).